# "I'm not crowding you, am I?" figuratively

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

In Persian, when we are criticized for our presence somewhere, we sometimes say "I'm not crowding you, am I?" It is used figuratively to mean "Why should you feel uncomfortable about my presence?" For example:

> A: Who told you to be here? Leave at once!

> B: I'm not crowding you, am I?

I wonder if there is something like that in English.

Comment: *I"m not crowding you, am I?* is a question. *You shouldn't feel uncomfortable about my presence* is a statement. They mean completely different things. It's not possible for one to be used figuratively to mean the other. Plus, *I'm not crowing you, am I?* already ***is*** used in English. What's wrong with it that you need something else?

Comment: @JasonBassford - Okay, I revised my explanation. I know "I'm not crowing you, am I?" already is used in English, but can it be used to mean what it means in Persian? If not, is there any similar expression in English?

Answer (score 1):

Probably ***[in the way](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-way)*** conveys the meaning you are referring to:

> If you say that someone gets in the way or is in the way, you are annoyed because their presence or their actions stop you doing something properly.
>
> - 'We wouldn't get in the way,' Suzanne promised. 'We'd just stand quietly in a corner.'

(Collins)

Comment: How can it be used in my example? Is it as sarcastic as the Persian expression?

Comment: @Nima90 - the expression  can be used sarcastically, of course.

Answer (score 0):

How about the well-known phrase **too close for comfort**? From Lexico:

> **[too close for comfort](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/too_close_for_comfort)**: Dangerously or uncomfortably near, e.g., ‘the friendly stranger who suddenly comes too close for comfort’

Examples:

> Am I too close for comfort?

> I'm not **too close for comfort**, am I?

> I hope I'm not **too close for comfort**.

Comment: "Too close for comfort" is normally used when describing dangerous circumstances, I don't think it applies to the situation the OP described.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for the comment, but it’s  used in both contexts, as per the definition. The example is the first one Lexico provides. There’s nothing dangerous about a “friendly stranger.”

Comment: The "friendly stranger" example seems to be describing a situation where a stranger who seemed friendly suddenly comes alarmingly close. There may not be any real danger in that situation, but for most people that would be a much higher level of discomfort than when someone they known gets equally close. I maintain that the expression would not normally be used in the OP's situation.

Comment: @nnnnnn I disagree. You’re grasping at straws now. The definition says “uncomfortably near.” Nothing dangerous about that. Dangerous was the thrust of you first comment.

Comment: My first comment did say "normally used", not "exclusively used". Counter examples exist, sure, but in practice I've never heard this expression used in the "I hope I'm not too close" sense.

Comment: @nnnnnn Okay, but I've heard it plenty of times.

Comment: Maybe there's some regional usage difference? In my experience even when a literal interpretation might seem to be about somebody sitting physically close, the subtext is that the speaker is worried about what that proximity might lead to. (This applies both within my real life experience and in fiction that I've read.)